# Creating a fantasy-style potion as a game prop

Tags: props, potions

I am due to run a game at a convention in the new year and want to pull out all the stops to make it memorable. One idea I have is to actually produce a potion for the player to drink once the character has found it. I have done this once before at my weekly game where I used an ornate balsamic vinegar bottle and papaya juice with purple food colouring and it worked fine, but I want to see if I wan take it to the next level.

So that was the background, here are my questions:

- Where can I find affordable bottles with a fantasy potion look to them?
- What substance would look and taste interesting in this situation?
- Is it just a bad idea to try get a player I haven't met before to drink an potion? Something tells me some people might be sceptical.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28799/9058

Comment: The other question focuses on appearance, but these questions highlight other facets. Note the plural: please separate these into their own so that answers to each may be voted on in their own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just address the "is this a good idea?" part of your question, since [the rest has been covered elsewhere](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28799/9058) already.

There isn't the same degree of established trust at a con to make a drinkable prop work. Because of that, presenting it would be an imposition on trust that isn't there, which may actually *impair* the little trust that these people have already given you by sitting down at your table and committing a time slot to your game.

Ideally, trust grows during play, which is part of the process of "getting into" your game. Decreasing that trust with a dubious prop may make the rest of the game suffer in unexpected ways, if it makes players draw away, disengage, or mistrust your GMing in general.

[There are ways to make it look impressive](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28799/9058), but looking impressive isn't relevant until you've already established a context in which a drinkable prop is appropriate. Consider: would *you* drink an art project that some stranger pulled out of his (unrefrigerated) backpack at a con?